# How to inherit from one parent or another one (not both)

Tags: python, oop

I don't know if this isn't antipattern but I have two parent classes and I need a child class to inherit only from one of them. Example:

```py
class ParA:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def f(self):
        print("method in parA")


class ParB:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def f(self):
        print("method in parB")


class Child(ParA, ParB):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        if "some_condition":
            pass # inherit from ParA
        elif "some_other_condition":
            pass # inherit from ParB


child = Child()
child.f()
```

After some googling I've found it might be possible to achieve this with `__getattribute__` method but I don't know how to implement it. Any help and explanations welcome!

Comment: `class Child(ParA, ParB)` will always inherit from both. I recommend removing your `Child` class and creating an instance of `ParA` or `ParB` inside your if statement (no inheritance required)

Comment: Imagine ParA is an Automobile and ParB is an Animal. You can create a class Child that you could make it inherit from Automobile so it becomes a Car or inherit from the class Animal and become a Dog. But this things are so different that it would make more sense to have a class Dog that inherits only from Animal and a different class Car that inherits only from Automobile.

Comment: If you only want to inherit from one, then only specify the one you want. Inheritance is a property of the *class*, not an instance of the class. (I.e., `__init__` is the wrong place to decide what type you want `self` to have; `__init__` is called on an instance of `Child` that has already been created.)

Comment: What you want, like @byxor said, is a factory function that decides whether to instantiate `ParA` or `ParB`, not a subclass of either class.